# If universe is expanding then relative to what?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, universe

I am very keen about the fact that universe is expanding.If something expands, it expands relative to something else. If the universe is expanding, then it must expand relative to something else. What is that **something else** here? I am asking this question as if everything is contained in the universe itself,then where  does that **something else** live?

Comment: See also [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/) as this explains what exactly we mean by the expansion.

Comment: @   John Rennie Why my below question was not addressed properly if universe expands relative to something the frame of reference must me same in both the questions? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487769/