# Doesn't the universe violate the law of conservation of linear momentum?

Tags: cosmology, momentum, conservation-laws, universe

As the mass of universe is not constant, it means that its linear momentum is not constant. But thinking in another way, is the universe subjected to a net external force? But what is external for the universe? The universe itself comprises of everything, so shouldn't every interaction be internal?

As every interaction is internal, there must be no external force, and the linear momentum of the universe must be constant!

Two different aspects give two different results. I am quite confused. Does the universe violate law of conservation of linear momentum?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487769/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic It was about Big Bang. So are you saying that I should delete it?

Comment: @Unique Why do you think that the mass of the universe is not constant ? If we include energy with mass (using $E=mc^2$ equivalence) then every physical process that we know of conserves mass/energy in a closed system.

Comment: how could you possibly define momentum of the universe to begin with?

Comment: @Umaxo I define the linear momentum of the universe to be the sum of the individual momenta of each and every body

Comment: @Unique i am not sure if you can do such a thing. In GR summing momenta of different particles will  be dependent on how you do the sum (you need to transport all vectors to the same point to sum them and the result will depend on paths that you choose). Even if you could, this would give you only momentum of a matter inside the universe, not momentum of the universe.So the supposed force that would cause this momentum to change would live inside the universe, not outside of it.

Comment: @Umaxo but the momentum of any system is defined as the sum of individual momenta of each particle of the system

Comment: @Unique not in general relativity. And in classical physics this is defined only for material systems living on some kind of background. So if you have material system (the content of the universe) that has changing momentum, the force will be associated with the background itself, similar to how it is done for noninertial frames, where the fictious forces are generated by the frame you use

Answer (score 1):

The momentum of an object of growing mass can remain constant if the velocity of its centre of mass is zero. If the universe were growing in mass isotropically, and if its constituent parts were accelerating isotropically, then its overall momentum could remain zero (ie constant).