# Is momentum conserved in our current cosmological models?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, momentum, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

The [cosmological principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle) states that the universe, on large enough scales, is homogenous and isotropic. Noether's theorem says that space-translational invariance corresponds to conservation of momentum, so I am tempted to say momentum is conserved.

However, we cosmological redshift says that if a photon is emitted by a distant galaxy, its wavelength is redshifted by the time it travels a large enough distance, and therefore its momentum $p = \hbar/\lambda$ is decreased.

I know that energy is not conserved, because our models of cosmology are not time-translational invariant, so there's no surprise on the topic of energy conservation. However, I'm not sure how to reconcile homogeneity of space with the apparently violation of momentum conservation. What am I missing in my understanding?

---

There are at least two posts that ask similar questions:

- [Isn't Big Bang theory a violation of law of conservation of linear momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487769)
- [Doesn't the universe violate the law of conservation of linear momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508641)

However, both of them fail to be duplicates.
The first one applies reasoning using Newtonian mechanics, which is not what my post asks about, and I understand that Newtonian mechanics doesn't apply to cosmology. The second one talks about momentum conservation but it asks about the change in mass of the universe. It is not explained what exactly he means, and I don't talk about mass.

My question specifically talks about the reconciliation of the homogeneity of space and Noether's theorem, which aren't mentioned in the above posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508641/2451

Comment: 1. Note that Noether's theorem assumes an action formulation. Which action are you using? 2. Also how do you define momentum of the universe?

Comment: @Qmechanic You are correct that I need an action/lagrangian here. My understanding is weak in cosmology, so I wouldn't know what action/lagrangian to consider, but if it helps, I am thinking of a photon in a universe with the FLRW metric.

Comment: At https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6977 , Nikodem Poplawski's torsion-based cosmological model (which I believe relies on the Principle of Stationary Action) arrives at an energy & momentum totalling zero, implying the existence of dark matter :  However, far from relying on anything Newtonian, his model relies on 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory.  I'm far from being able to apply it in an answer, although  ECT's said to "reduce to GR" in vacuum, which might leave it compatible with the FLRW metric.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747350/2451